# Create pages from MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a `MySQL` database containing several tables. I want `WordPress` to create pages for each row in the main table by querying other tables for more information. I have `WordPress` and `MySQL` installed on my server. If there are resources that show how this can be done, please point me in that direction.

Comment: SQL queries with `wp_insert_post`.

Answer (score 1):

You really should dive in more yourself. I'm not sure how good of a programmer you are, but you almost certain have to start to write a script that extracts all the information you want from the database and put this in an array.

Once you've done that, you can use this data to create new posts. WordPress has some great functions you can use to accomplish this. Especially wp_insert_post

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

To add addition information to a post you can use update_post_meta

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta